# Outbound IIS Rewrite rule on script with boolean attribute isn't working

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to add a version querystring to some CSS and JS files via an Outbound rewrite rule as follows:

```
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="AppendQueryStringToAssets" preCondition="IsHtmlFile">
      <match filterByTags="Link, Script" pattern="^(.*app.*s)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}?v=1.0.0" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="IsHtmlFile">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>
```

Then in my HTML I have the following elements:

```
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/app.css">
<script type="module" src="../../js/app.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="../../js/app.es5.js"></script>
```

Per [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element) `nomodule` is a boolean attribute, so doesn't need a value specified.

However, when viewing the served html, I get the following (last src doesn't have a query string appended):

```
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/app.css?v=1.0.0">
<script type="module" src="../../js/app.js?v=1.0.0"></script>
<script nomodule src="../../js/app.es5.js"></script>
```

If I move the `nomodule` attribute after the `src` attribute it works, similarly if I give `nomodule` a value it works, but neither of those seem like they should be needed:

```
<script src="../../js/app.es5.js?v=1.0.0" nomodule></script>
```

Is there a way to support this via the config to ensure it doesn't matter how the script element is written?

I tried creating a custom tag `script nomodule` but that didn't seem to make any difference either.

Comment: Feel this is a bug within the UrlRewrite module, so [have also raised](https://forums.iis.net/p/1250633/2160768.aspx?p=True&t=637250202671921408) on the IIS forums.